# Having problems with the GUI on ubuntu gnome 15.04. Linux responds, but the GUI does not

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics-card, gnome, gui

For some reason, whenever I try to install ubuntu gnome 15.04 on my computer (specs listed below) It boots, I can get to the gnome login screen, and I can log in. But after I log in, it brings me to a black screen and I have to go to the terminal via ctrl+alt+f*.

Is this a hardware incompatibility? Is it something to do with xserver? I tried installing both closed source and open source AMD graphics card drivers, but that's all so far. Any suggestions?

Specs:
i7-4820k
Gigabyte GA-X79-UP4 Mobo
24GB DDR3-1600
Radeon HD 7770

Comment: update your question with your /var/log/xorg.0.log

Comment: Give a look to the output of dmesg too.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia will do. It's rather late here now so I'll include the log tomorrow.